# Can redundant "using"s degrade performance

Tags: c#, reference

Just a performance question ...

Let's say I have 5 classes and each of them have a reference to System.Data and a homegrown Library.  The 5 classes in question are a part of a Class Library and will eventually be built and published up to some web applications as a reference.

Is there any size/performance gained by taking the functions that reference System.Data and the other Library to their own class so that the number of times System.Data and my other Library gets referenced is reduced from 5 to 1?  Common Sense is telling me that it doesn't matter because the DLLs would get read at the point of one of those functions being executed so it wouldn't matter where they sit or how many times you have "using System.Data" in your codebase ... but I've been wrong before :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No - `using` directives don't add references to *assemblies*; they import *namespaces* for code in the same scope. All they're doing is allowing you to use

```
Foo foo = new Foo(); // etc
```

in your code instead of

```
Some.Namespace.Containing.Foo foo = new Some.Namespace.Containing.Foo();
```

They don't change which assemblies are being referenced at all. It's important to understand the different between namespaces and assemblies - unfortunately as they often use the same names, it can be confusing. As an example of where they're different, the `Enumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace is in the `System.Core` assembly.

Comment: Excellent.  So the using just lets VS know which namespaces to bring in for use with the intellisense?  And the actual assemblies are not utilized until the executing code hits a reference to it?

Comment: @cavillac: Not just for Intellisense, but for the compiler. The assembly references are used during compilation as well (otherwise the compiler wouldn't know which types and members are available), but they're generally lazily loaded at execution time.